# Google Recaptcha with rails Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, recaptcha

Im adding google recaptcha to my rails application with devise.
I did the following:

```
#In my gemfile:
    gem "recaptcha", require: "recaptcha/rails"
```

In my initializers:

```
#In config/initializers/recaptcha.rb
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.site_key  = '********************'
  config.secret_key = '********************'
  # Uncomment the following line if you are using a proxy server:
  # config.proxy = 'http://myproxy.com.au:8080'
end
```

In application.html.erb layout file:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

In devise/registrations/new.html.erb

```
  <%= flash[:recaptcha_error] %>
  <%= recaptcha_tags %>
```

Registration Controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    prepend_before_action :check_captcha, only: [:create] # Change this to be any actions you want to protect.
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, :only => [:create]


  protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,:username, :name, :country, :sex, :age_group, :race) }
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :remember_me,:username, :name, :country, :sex, :age_group, :race) }
    end

  private
    def check_captcha
      unless verify_recaptcha
        self.resource = resource_class.new configure_permitted_parameters
        #resource.validate # Look for any other validation errors besides Recaptcha
        respond_with_navigational(resource) { render :new }
      end
  end
end
```

When I signup, the page is redirected to my signup page itself. Shows recaptcha error message over recaptcha element. 
The server logs shows:

> Filter chain halted as :check_captcha rendered or redirected

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-23 13:01:10 +0530
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Dv6+vEH1KlMbrqssbX1nW9PbDYtmu+92QAZVvGO5JedpmHj8S8Jr4vuvbUUuBwWQO6MK04daOqzCZyOPXMvnLw==", "user"=>{"username"=>"ssfafa", "name"=>"afafaf", "country"=>"AI", "age_group"=>"dffssaf", "sex"=>"Male", "race"=>"sfsfsf", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
  Rendering devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (17.5ms)
Filter chain halted as :check_captcha rendered or redirected
Completed 200 OK in 96ms (Views: 94.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

User is not added to database. Unable to complete registration. Please resolve this issue . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why this not working, if your configuration ok then also not working then try to after comment out `check_captcha` method then override `create` method like below

```
def create
    if verify_recaptcha
      super
    else
        flash.now[:error] = "Recaptcha cannot be blank; please try again"
        render :new
    end
end
```

and routes

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

Hope it helps